# Linux sh scripting "if" combinations doesn't work as expected

Tags: linux, shell, if-statement

I am trying combine if and else in linux sh scripting

Why script in linux sh like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
[ "$1" ] && echo "000" || (echo 111; echo 222)
```

gives output without $1 variable as:

```
111
222
```

but this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
[ "$1" ] && echo "000" || (var1=111; var2=222)
echo "$var1"
echo "$var2"
```

without variable $1 gives empty output?

Comment: `()` creates a subshell. Variable assignments in a subshell do not persist when the shell exits.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `if`. Just write `(var1=123); echo $var1` and you'll see the problem.

Comment: Mind also that `a && b || c` is not quite identical to behavior of `if a; then b; else c; fi`. When you want `if`, _use_ `if`. See [BashPitfalls #22](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3)

Comment: You are putting an *action* as if it were **inside** a ternary if, which you are NOT --  The subshell is never reached, and this is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: If you want _grouping_ without a subshell, that's `{ var1=111; var2=222; }`, not `(var1=111; var2=222)`